# Animate leaving screen with React Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am developing a React Native application which uses [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) 
to manage the routing between screens.

I know reading [React Navigation documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#stacknavigatorconfig) and watching [this video](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-native-build-fine-grained-screen-transitions-with-a-custom-react-navigation-interpolator) on Egghead.io (highly suggested) that is possible to define custom animations for transitions between screens passing the `transitionConfig` property to a `StackNavigator`.

For example, the following code is defining a *slide from left* animation that is basically the mirror of the iOS default push animation:

```
const TransitionConfig = () => ({
    screenInterpolator: ({ layout, position, scene }) => {
        const { index } = scene
        const { initWidth } = layout

        const translateX = position.interpolate({
            inputRange: [index - 1, index, index + 1],
            outputRange: [-initWidth, 0, 0],
        })

        return {
            transform: [{ translateX }],
        }
    }
})

const MyNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        A: {screen: ScreenA},
        B: {screen: ScreenB},
    },
    { transitionConfig: TransitionConfig }
)
```

Considering the code above and the fact we are navigating from screen `A` to screen `B`, the `screenInterpolator` function body is basically describing the animation the screen `B` should follow **when it's going to appear** (it's reverted when it disappears). In this case the code it's saying to translate the screen `B` along the X axis to achieve a *slide in* effect.

Is it possible to also define the animation for **the screen that is disappearing** (screen `A` in our case)? I would like to define something like this:

- `B` should **appear** sliding from left to right
- `A` should **disappear** sliding from top to bottom

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found the answer by myself, I hope will help someone in the future.

I was wrong assuming that `screenInterpolator` is describing only the behaviour of the screen `B`, because is actually describing the animation of both `A` and `B`. Or better, it's the `interpolate` function with `inputRange` and `outputRange` that allows you to describe the animation for both the entering (`B`) and leaving (`A`) screen.

Let's have a closer look to this snippet, keeping in mind that the `interpolate` function is just creating a 1-1 association between the values of `inputRange` and `outputRange` (deeper explanation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations#interpolation)).

```
const { index } = scene

const translateX = position.interpolate({
    inputRange:  [index - 1, index, index + 1],
    outputRange: [-initWidth, 0, 0],
})
```

**Assumptions:**

- `B` and `A` are screens
- we are navigating from `A` to `B`
- `width(B) = width(A) = 320`
- `width(deviceScreen) = 320`
- `initWidth = 320`

**Explanation**

- `index-1` represents the screen that is going to appear (screen `B`) and it's mapped to `-initWidth`. With this we are saying that the screen it's going to appear (screen `B`) should be X-translated (respect the viewport) of a value equal its width. So it will start the animation from `X = 320` (i.e. outside the screen)
- `index` represents the screen that is going to appear, but once is appeared (still screen `B`). Mapping it to `0` we are saying that screen `B` once is appeared should be in position `X = 0`
- `index + 1` represents the screen once is going to disappear. This is what it led me to the error. At the beginning I thought this was still and **only** the screen `B`, but just when it would have disappeared because of a navigation like  `B->C`. However from our `A->B` point of view, it's the screen `A` the one that is going to disappear! So both line of thoughts are correct, it's all about seeing things from a different perspective. So, mapping `index+1` to `0` we are saying that screen `A` should stay at `X=0` when it's going to disappear (i.e. when `B` is going to appear)

**Result**

This is the animation realized by the code above. As you can see, the screen `A` remains where it is because of the association `index+1 <-> 0` (no translation, so no animation for screen `A`).

[image: Description here]

If we change the association of `index+1` to `index+1 <-> -initWidth`, then screen `A` will also be translated and hence animated :)

```
const translateX = position.interpolate({
  inputRange:  [index - 1, index, index + 1],
  outputRange: [initWidth, 0, -initWidth],
})
```

[image]

---

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally found what I needed.

Comment: Hey @toioski, do you have any idea how to do the same thing in `"react-navigation-stack": "2.0.14",`? the interface has changed since the update, and I can't figure out how to do the same thing you did

Comment: @VladyslavZavalykhatko hi, have you managed to port it to react navigation v5?

Comment: @Oleksii yeah, but was a long time ago, sorry

Comment: @VladyslavZavalykhatko found it, needed to google harder :\